# How can I get the hover text in selenium?

Tags: html, css, python-3.x, selenium

for example, in this url(https://www.agoda.com/sudima-lake-rotorua-hotel/hotel/rotorua-nz.html?finalPriceView=1&isShowMobileAppPrice=false&cid=-1&numberOfBedrooms=&familyMode=false&adults=2&children=0&rooms=1&maxRooms=0&checkIn=2022-12-4&isCalendarCallout=false&childAges=&numberOfGuest=0&missingChildAges=false&travellerType=-1&showReviewSubmissionEntry=false&currencyCode=USD&isFreeOccSearch=false&isCityHaveAsq=false&tspTypes=2&los=6&searchrequestid=556b0085-60c1-4ea4-aed1-9783838b9351), when my mouse move on the picture, and it will show the words "This offer will accommodate your travel group!", "This offer includes 1 Room(s), 2 Adult(s).".
[image]

Here is my code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from time import sleep
from random import randint
        
user_agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1866.237 Safari/537.36"
options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
options.add_argument(f"--user-agent={user_agent}")
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
driver.get("https://www.agoda.com/sudima-lake-rotorua-hotel/hotel/rotorua-nz.html?finalPriceView=1&isShowMobileAppPrice=false&cid=-1&numberOfBedrooms=&familyMode=false&adults=2&children=0&rooms=1&maxRooms=0&checkIn=2022-12-4&isCalendarCallout=false&childAges=&numberOfGuest=0&missingChildAges=false&travellerType=-1&showReviewSubmissionEntry=false&currencyCode=USD&isFreeOccSearch=false&isCityHaveAsq=false&tspTypes=2&los=6&searchrequestid=556b0085-60c1-4ea4-aed1-9783838b9351")
width, height = driver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.scrollWidth"), driver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.scrollHeight")
driver.set_window_size(1920, height*2.1)
sleep(randint(15, 20))
res_list = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div[class="CapacityTooltipBody-item"]')
res_list = [i.text for i in res_list]
print("res_list", res_list)
# res_list []
```

How can I get the hover text("This offer will accommodate your travel group!", "This offer includes 1 Room(s), 2 Adult(s).") in selenium?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the tooltip using the following CSS Selector:

```css
div.rc-tooltip:not(.rc-tooltip-hidden)
```

This means get all `div`s that have the class `rc-tooltip` and not `rc-tooltip-hidden`. The latter class gets removed from the tooltip to show it.